# como elijo compilar entre una version de 32 bits y una de 64 bits?

Tags: c++, c, compilar, cmake, blender

Quiero compilar blender 2.79 y tengo ya instalado source code.

- blender Source Code
- lib

  - win64_vc14       `x64`
  - windows_vc14     `x32`

*lo que no se hacer !*...
es cómo estructurar la línea de comando para indicarle a **`cmake`** 
para obtener una compilación `32 bits` **o** `64 bits`.

Seguí la guía de [blender.org](https://www.blender.org/) pero es para **`blender 2.8`**, cambiaron muchas cosas tuve que averiguar cuál era el link de la rama `2.79b` cómo hacer checkout para la rama 2.79b.

[image: carpetas git]

Answer (score 0):

---

Según tengo entendido, debes añadir la ruta del compilador a la variable de entorno `Path`. Para esto, ve a **Panel de Control** > **Sistema y seguridad** > **Sistema** > **Configuración avanzada del sistema** > **Variables de entorno**. Haz doble click en la variable `Path` del listado **Variables del sistema**, dale a Nuevo, pega la ruta y dale a **Aceptar**.

Si la ruta que has pegado es del compilador de 64 bits, el comando en **cmd** para compilar utilizará este. Si es del compilador de 32 bits, utilizará este otro.

En mi caso, la ruta del compilador que utilizo es `D:\Programas\MinGW\bin`